# Prioritize a website in Google Search results when you are searching for something

Tags: google-search

Everyone knows Stack Exchange is the best (that's why you are reading this).

Let's say that I want Stack Exchange website to be **always** the first in my Google search results whenever I search for something, how can I do this?

Comment: First, this question is is dire need of expansion. Please add background on what /exactly/ you are try to do, why, and a well phrased example if possible. Second, this is called Search Engine Optimization (SEO).

Comment: I'm sure you know you can do "site:stackexchange.com" to *filter* results, but I don't know a way of prioritizing by site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use search parameter by url instead like so:

> google.com/search?q=hello+world+as_sitesearch=stackexchange.com

And just link it to the omnibox search engine parameter.

I know it isn't the actual answer to my question but it solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

- Make yourself a [Google Search Engine](https://cse.google.com/cse/all).
- Put StackExchange (or whatever) into the Sites list.
- Beside **Sites to Search**, choose "Search the entire web but emphasis
  included sites".

Then run your searches from this.

You may like to embed it into a blog post or website page somewhere to make it easier to get to.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your prompt reply. Unfortunately it wasn't the method that I preferred. But +1 for your help!